# Geoserver not showing compressed rasters?

Tags: geoserver

beginner here.  I'm practicing loading a raster file into Geoserver, and loading/viewing it works fine with my uncompressed (1.2GB) tif (seems I can use either GeoTiff or Worldfile options just fine), but it will simply not display compressed tifs using the same workflow.

A bit more detail of what I've done:

- I merged some landsat images into a large GeoTiff via gdalwarp (1.2GB file)
- I use listgeo command to create a tfw file associated with the tif
- I edited the tif in GIMP to adjust some color settings, etc, which loses the georeference data
- After GIMP edits complete, I use gdal_edit.py to reassign srs (EPSG:3857) and ensure tfw has same name as tif file.
- At this point, I can then load the large tif/tfw files (1.2GB) onto my Geoserver as a store and then publish as layer, and I can see/zoom,etc the raster just fine in layer preview (openlayers).
- However, if I use any compression ("gdal_translate -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES in.tif out.tif" or COMPRESS=JPEG) and upload this smaller (~200MB) file (and associated tfw) to geoserver as a store and publish as layer (same procedure as uncompressed tif), it simply does not show when I try to view in layer preview (open layers) as the larger one does.  The window's coordinate area seems fine, but it is just a blank box with no visible raster!

Does anybody have any ideas why I might be experiencing this?

---

I figured out I was missing a step in the re-georeferencing (I used gdal_translate's -a_ullr to add in upper right, lower left, etc coords back into the tif).  So I can now get the properly georeferenced compressed tif to show, so I'm assuming it had something to do with that.  I still can't get the non-properly georeferenced compressed version to show on Geoserver, though the non-properly georeferenced uncompressed one does just fine still.  This is GeoServer v2.9.0. I'll consider this matter resolved for now.

Comment: We need to know that geoserver version, plus paste here the output of the gdalinfo on one of the images that are failing to load. It would also help to see the log of GeoServer (use a verbose level) when the image does not show.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, if someone knows the answer please post the solution